# Regular Expression to validate xx-xxxxxxx or xxx-xx-xxxx

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a single regular expression validator that will only acccept values in the following formats:-

string1 = xxx-xx-xxxx

or

string1 = xx-xxxxxxx

How can I make the regex accept both kinds of values for the same element?

The x's represent numbers only.

so total number of digits = 9 (anything between 0-9)

total number of elements in the value is either 11 or 10... depending on which format.

and total number of dashes is either 2 or 1.

How can I write this into a regular expression? Can anyone point me towards the right direction :- article/website.

I do have some knowledge on regular expressions, where i can verify phone numbers and dates and such. So a little help will go a long way. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried ? Can dashes be anywhere ? Even on the start/end of the string ?

Comment: no the format has to be the same 123-45-6789 or 12-3456789

Comment: I can build a regex to check for [0-9]{9} digits. and then to check for a dash separately. But I don't know how to combine these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$|^\d{2}-\d{7}$
```

try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iB9oZ1/1

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Its nice to know that after using regex101 for many years, all I get now is.. 'Unfortunately it seems your browser does not meed the criteria to properly render and utilize this website.'. I am using FF, and now use regexr.com

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex,

```
^(?:\d{3}-\d{2}-|\d{2}-\d{3})\d{4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uZ7jG7/2)

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
  -                        '-'
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
  -                        '-'
 |                        OR
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
  -                        '-'
  \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
)                        end of grouping
\d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: Thanks for elaboration Avinash. I do understand what is going on in both the examples (yours and vks). Your's is a bit more compact that vks. Kudos.